# Share data between 2 containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I do a Symfony project with Docker. In development, I mount my source folder in Nginx and PHP-FPM containers. But for the production, I want to put the code in the PHP-FPM container to do an app container, and share the code with the Nginx container.

In my Dockerfile, I use a `VOLUME /var/www/html`, but how can I permit the nginx container to access this volume (in docker-compose file) ?
Before the v3, I know there was a `volumes_from`, but not anymore.

I want place the code inside the container like say here (https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/)

> Removing any volume bindings for application code, so that code stays inside the container and can’t be changed from outside

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it appear we can use a named volume to do it, remove the `VOLUME` from the Dockerfile, then just define a name volume, and it takes the value of the first container.

```
version: '3'

services:
    nginx:
        build: ./docker/nginx
        volumes:
            - app_data:/var/www/html:ro
        depends_on:
           - app

    app:
        build: ./
        volumes:
            - app_data:/var/www/html:rw
        networks:
            - default

volumes:
    app_data:
        driver: local
```